# Is there a difference between Experience Design(XD) and UX design

Tags: design, ux-field, ux-designer, experience

Going through various sources, I am getting that UX designing is a perspective limited to designing services and products as per audience and Experience design holds more artistic temperament for implementing imagination without a specific audience.I mean if a person is more inclined to just express his imagination without much of rules and guidelines for any "corporate" or "professional" sense and also is not limited to just painting his imagination and can play around with objects and environment that even serves an experience but not intended to give a specific result. Is there any help from UX design field or am I right when i think that the above stated is a separate field known as XD or am I not clear about the nature of UX and confusing it with XD which are different names of same class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sachin, correct me if I am wrong, I Google and sharing you the information below from Wikipedia, Quora, Youtube along with source link because the topic is very well explained in detail.

**User Experience Design**
via: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience_design

User experience design (UX, UXD, UED or XD) is the process of enhancing user satisfaction by improving the usability, accessibility, and pleasure provided in the interaction between the user and the product. User experience design encompasses traditional human–computer interaction (HCI) design, and extends it by addressing all aspects of a product or service as perceived by users.

**Experience Design**
via: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experience_design

Experience design (XD) is the practice of designing products, processes, services, events, omnichannel journeys, and environments with a focus placed on the quality of the user experience and culturally relevant solutions. An emerging discipline, experience design draws from many other disciplines including cognitive psychology and perceptual psychology, linguistics, cognitive science, architecture and environmental design, haptics, hazard analysis, product design, theatre, information design, information architecture, ethnography, brand strategy, interaction design, service design, storytelling, heuristics, technical communication, and design thinking.

**UX vs XD also discussed in Quora**: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-User-Experience-UX-and-Experience-Design-XD

**Jared Spool**: In general, I don't see a distinction. User Experience Design and Experience Design seem to be interchangable terms. Of course, if you analyze something enough, you can derive semantics that mean practically anything. I wouldn't be surprised if someone comes up with a semantic razor that tries to distinguish the two. However, in my world, I couldn't explain any substantial or meaningful difference. (*On a side note, there are those who are talking about Service Design. I'd be hard pressed to list any differences between Service Design and Experience Design.*)

**Nick Finck**: This comes down to a debate on semantics.  Neither side I feel is more wrong or right.  But lets ask the questions... Q. Is a person a user? When I eat ice cream do I describe myself as a ice cream user? Is the process for designing the interior of a hotel that much different than the process of designing the user interface of a mobile app?

While these two things are often used (correctly or incorrectly) interchangeably, the de facto, or common usage, of user experience design has to do technology (physical devices, digital systems, etc.), but rarely with environments, human to human communication, broadcast & print media, etc. There are other words that are more commonly used for these such as customer, listener, viewer, participant, client, etc... but not often user.

That said, I believe the addition or the absence of the word user is typically to show the intended scope of what one is describing; something related to technology, or something that could potentially include technology but is of larger scope.

**Youtube**: Tedde Van Gelderen, talks about the Importance of Experience Design

- Part 1 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oRvyMxl9cgo
- Part 2 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CO6fDTpulWQ
- Part 3 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7sL9g8homo
- Part 4 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n7ajTg7cEEE

*Kind request to community members for sharing above details from the sources because it would be a long answer explaining UX and XD in details in comment. I'm not so sure sharing sources link is allow or not.*

Comment: very nice detail.i definitely need to touch up on some experience design concepts

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion UX design and XD design are different concepts. XD design has still more limited value compared to the UX design. I agree with a comparison of these concepts in this article http://www.distinct-ux.com/ux-vs-xd-whats-the-difference/

Answer (score 0):

When it comes down to what designers need to do, go with Jared Spool's answer, quoted above. You can include the word "user" or leave it off, but experiences are had by people (and other sentient beings), so we're talking about designing things that people experience. The scope might be narrow (a screen in an app or a web page), or the scope might be wide (end-to-end customer journey with digital and physical touchpoints plus communications), but the core methods and purpose are the same.